# Is it possible to retrieve icon of the iCloud user from CloudKit?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, icloud-api

I need that small photo I have set up in my iCloud. Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the small avatar associated with an iCloud account?

If so, then no, I don't believe this is possible. The CloudKit discoverability APIs all return users in the form of CKDiscoveredUserInfo objects. These are currently limited to providing first name, last name and userRecordID.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKDiscoveredUserInfo_class/

Comment: Can you explain this part of the documentation related to `displayContact` property: "Contains the given and family name of the user `who is not` associated with the local Address Book. (read-only)"  Does this mean, that user who is already in our Address Book, will have full CNContact info? In my experience, you're right. But this docs is very vague. Maybe I'm doing something wrong...